# Layers of InnerHML

Tags: excel, vba

I have accessed the source code of a webpage and Looped through each ("div") `elementByTagName` and returned the `InnerHTML`, the value returned is limited in scope. The best way to phrase it is that it returns the `InnerHTML` but the `InnerHTML` has another layer of information that is not being disclosed. However, if I was to use "FireFox" and Inspect Element and right-click the element and "Copy Inner HTML" then ALL of the `innerHTML` and layers of data will be available.

```
Set Levels = ie.Document.body.getElementsByTagName("div")

For Each Level In Levels
    If Level.ID = "application" Then
        Ans = Level.InnerHTML
        Cells(20, 1).Value = Ans

    End If
Next Level
```

How do I access all the `InnerHTML` layers? Or at the very least, how do I set the `innerHTML` (first layer) as a variable so I can loop through the various inner elements to acquire further information (second layer, third layer, etc.....)?

Answer (score 0):

If the div has an id then you can get it directly using

```
Dim d
Set d = ie.Document.getElementById("application")
```

If you then want to access elements within that div then you can use that in place of the document object as your starting point.

Eg:

```
Dim divs
Set divs = d.getElementsByTagName("div")
```

I can't account for why innerHTML isn't giving you the correct result, unless it's a timing issue (e.g. the page is not yet fully-rendered when your code runs)